# Continuing a while loop over a set of points after it reaches a None value

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, control-flow

I have some code I have been working on to trace a shape around a cloud of points. Esencially I have a while loop that checks if the next_point is equal to the start point, and if not it updates the current_point and next_point.

I originally had to code run as a recursion as such:

```
 def recur(self, p):
 """
 @params p: [2x2] ndarray defining a vector to measure angle from
 self.next_point: the next point that the loop will travel to next
 self.start: the start point of the loop. [2x2] ndarray defining a starting  line  
 self.k: number of neighbors to search for further in the code (needs to be updated when self.next_point is None
 self.
 new_vect: line connecting current and next_point to use as next angle reference
"""                                                                                  
        current_point = p[0]                                                                              
        next_point = self.get_next_point(p)                                                               
        if next_point is None:                                                                            
            self.k+=1                                                                                                                                                                     
            self.recur(p)                                                                                                                                             
        elif next_point[0] == self.start[0] and next_point[1] == self.start[1]:                     
            print("DONE!")                                                                                
            return None                                                                                   
        else:                                                                                             
            new_vect = np.concatenate([[next_point, current_point]])                                                                                                                   
            self.n+=1                                                                                                                                                   
            self.recur(new_vect)                                                                          
        return self.line
```

This worked for small datasets, but I hit the recursion limit on the large dataset I need to actually acomplish this on.

So I tried to rewrite this with a while loop and it mostly works until I hit a point where the next_point is None (get_next_point returns None because none of the neighbors it iterates through fulfills the conditions I need). In that case, like in the above recursion, I need to update k by 1 (number of neighbors to search for) and then try that same point again.

```
def loop(self, start):                                                                               
        self.current_vect = start                                                                         
        self.current_point = start[0]                                                                                                                
            while self.next_point[0] != self.start[0][0] or self.next_point[1] != self.start[0][1]:       │
                self.next_point = self.get_next_point(self.current_vect)                                                                           
                self.new_vect = np.concatenate([[self.next_point, self.current_point]])                                                                                            
                self.current_vect = self.new_vect                                                         
                self.current_point = self.next_point                                                                                                                
        print("DONE!")
```

Once the loop hits a next_point that is None, then the loop crashes since it cannot compare None to the start point. I'm having trouble with that last part within the while loop and I was hoping somebody could push me in the right direction. Is there a way I can update k and then continue the while loop on the same point? For example if self.current_point = ([1,2]) and get_next_point(current_point) returns None, I need to update k and the run get_next_point on the same point ([1,2]).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the loop on the None values.

for example:

```
#this variation will print the statement
x="some_value"
if x:
    print("i am here")

#this variation wont print the statement

x=None
if x:
    print("i am here")
```

so you have to do something like

```
if list_x:
    #start your loop
    for i in ...
else:
    pass
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Do you mean something like:

`  if point is None:
        while while self.next_point[0] != start:
            #DO STUFF
    else: 
        pass`